# Knowing if a twitter user has location enabled

Tags: twitter

I'm writing an app that posts tweets to Twitter.  I'd like to offer the option of including location in the tweet, which is available via POST statuses/update using the lat and long parameters.

Here's my problem: if a twitter account hasn't turned on location tweeting via https://twitter.com/settings/account "Add a location to my Tweets", then I can send the tweet with the location info, but the location info won't appear.  This is a GOOD THING for the user's security, but an annoyance for me because:

If the user hasn't turned on this feature, I shouldn't be offering it in my UI.  It's a bad user experience to let the user THINK he can include location information, but then not have the information appear because of some setting outside my control.

So here's my question: Is there a way, through the twitter api, to know if a user has turned on this setting in his twitter settings? I've looked through GET users/show, but can't find anything there that mentions what I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after some more digging, it turns out that there's a "geo_enabled" key that is included in responses from several twitter endpoints.  It's accessible from [GET account/settings](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/settings), of course, but it also often appears in responses to [GET users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) and probably several other endpoints that return user data.

If "geo_enabled" is true, then the user has agreed to let location data get posted in his tweets. If it's false or doesn't appear, then I'm going to assume that the user hash't turned on this feature.